# How to select record from 5th row without using where query in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, paging

I have a table and that has 10 records and fetch records from 5 to 10 without using where condition.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When asking a question, it's expected that you show your research, or attempts, to solve the problem yourself first. To get you on the right track I recommend looking at `FETCH` and `OFFSET`: [Using OFFSET and FETCH to limit the rows returned](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#using-offset-and-fetch-to-limit-the-rows-returned). If you don't understand, then please post your attempt and explain why it didn't work as you expect, or provide the error message you received.

Comment: Also, explain why you have the requirement "without using where condition"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [OFSET-FETCH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). It should be something like this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM mytable
ORDER BY id
OFFSET 5 ROWS  
FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY;
```

As the syntax above is supported from SQL Server 2012, for early version you can use ranking function:

```
WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT *
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id) AS rn
    FROM mytable
)   
SELECT *
FROM DataSource
WHERE rn >= 5 AND rn <=10;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to execute the query is using the [TOP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) clause, according to example found [here](https://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/2013/how-to-select-bottom-n-rows-in-a-table-through-sin.html):

```
SELECT TOP(5) *
FROM mytable
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

Hope it helps.